# Error in ./node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-libcurl

I'm a C++ developer and beginner in the Node world. 
I would like to create a CEP and VUE based Photoshop plugin. 
The skeleton plugin works well. 
I would like to use node-libcurl package for this plugin.

I installed libcurl  -  It's OK.

```
npm i node-libcurl --save
```

I put down into my C4.js

```
const { curly } = require('node-libcurl');
```

When I want to build my project I got this error:

> INFO  Starting development server... 98% after emitting CopyPlugin
>
> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error
> 7:26:51 PM  error  in
> ./node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders (Source code omitted for > > this binary file)
>
> @ ./node_modules/node-libcurl/dist/Easy.js 5:17-60  
> @ ./node_modules/node-libcurl/dist/index.js  
> @ ./src/c4/C4.js  
> @ ./src/main.js
> @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.22:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node
> (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

I tried this webpack.config.js in .... \node_modules\node-libcurl

```js
module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.node$/,
        loader: "node-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

... but it did not work.

I appreciate any help 
Thx:
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

It was my fail.

I got answer from developer.

> This library is not supposed to work in the Browser, it is a backend-only library.

/Carlos